# simple setup.py seemingly broken

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

On Windows 7, running Python 2.7, `python setup.py install` installs [python-money](http://code.google.com/p/python-money/), but doesn't install the included money.django package.

The setup.py file can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-money/source/browse/trunk/setup.py). I've included it below for convenience:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

def read(fname):
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

setup(
        name = "python-money",
        version = "0.6",
        author = "Jordan Dimov",
        author_email = "s3x3y1@gmail.com",
        maintainer = "Ben Coughlan",
        maintainer_email = "ben.coughlan@gmail.com",
        description = ("Data classes to represent Money and Currency types"),
        license = "BSD",
        keywords = "money currency",
        url = "http://code.google.com/p/python-money",
        packages = ['money', 'money.django'],
        long_description = read('README.txt'),
        classifiers = [
                "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
                "Environment :: Plugins",
                "Environment :: Other Environment",
                "Framework :: Django",
                "Operating System :: OS Independent",
                "Intended Audience :: Developers",
                "Intended Audience :: Financial and Insurance Industry",
                "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
                "Programming Language :: Python",
                "Topic :: Office/Business :: Financial",
        ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `packages = find_packages()`. It should automatically pick up your packages. You can even run `find_packages()` and copy-paste it's output into `setup.py` -- this way you'll know what you're doing wrong.

http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#using-find-packages